# E/Camera: Error 2 in Logcat when using camera in app (Java App Development for Android)

Tags: java, android

Been through hell coding my first android app.

*E/Camera: Error 2* in *Logcat* whenever camera is used (the error code is for multiple camera uses)

I have attached the entire project if you want to and can run it. Kindly help.

[Link to Project on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G0gMJXnAhYAcC6zMUqMLatOfz80RG410?usp=sharing)

I am also attaching the code to the main files in this post if you want to view it directly.

Here is **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cse535a1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.hardware.*;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private Camera c;
    private CameraView cv1;
    private FrameLayout view_camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))) {
            this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture video_capture;

        Button button_symptoms = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_symptoms);
        Button button_upload_signs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_upload_signs);
        Button button_measure_heart_rate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_measure_heart_rate);
        Button button_measure_respiratory_rate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_measure_respiratory_rate);

        c = getcam();
        cv1 = new CameraView(getApplicationContext(), c);
        view_camera = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.view_camera);
        view_camera.addView(cv1);

        TextView finger_on_sensor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_finger_on_sensor);
        finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        finger_on_sensor.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg_view, MotionEvent arg_me) {
                finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                File file_video = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/video_finger.mp4");
                final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

                Intent intent_record_video = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 45);
                Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.cse535a1.provider", file_video);
                intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                c.release();
                startActivityForResult(intent_record_video, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                c.stopPreview();
                return true;
            }
        });

        button_symptoms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Loggin_symptoms.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        button_upload_signs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {

            }
        });

        button_measure_heart_rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        button_measure_respiratory_rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                SensorManager manager_sensor = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
                Sensor sensor_accelerometer = manager_sensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
                manager_sensor.registerListener(MainActivity.this, sensor_accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg_event) {
        float x = arg_event.values[0];
        float y = arg_event.values[1];
        float z = arg_event.values[2];
        Log.i("ACCELEROMETER", String.valueOf(x) + ' ' + String.valueOf(y) + ' ' + String.valueOf(z));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg_sensor, int arg_accuracy) {

    }

    public Camera getcam() {
        Camera c = null;
        try { c = Camera.open(0); }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        c = getcam();
        cv1 = new CameraView(getApplicationContext(), c);
        view_camera.addView(cv1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        c.stopPreview();
        c.release();
        c = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Here is **CameraView.java**

```
package com.example.cse535a1;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder holder_surface;
    private Camera camera_selected;

    public CameraView(Context arg_context, Camera arg_camera) {
        super(arg_context);
//        Log.i("Cam", "constructor");
        camera_selected = arg_camera;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        holder_surface = getHolder();
        holder_surface.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        holder_surface.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg_holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            camera_selected.setPreviewDisplay(arg_holder);
            camera_selected.startPreview();
//            Log.i("Cam", "surface creator");
        } catch (IOException e) {
//            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg_holder, int arg_format, int arg_width, int arg_height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (holder_surface.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera_selected.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera_selected.setPreviewDisplay(holder_surface);
            camera_selected.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
//            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are updated files. It seems removing statements which release camera seems to remove errors of using camera after releasing. Unlocking the camera in `onPause()` removed-> *E/Camera: Error 2*

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cse535a1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.hardware.*;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

import java.io.File;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private Camera c;
    private CameraView cv1;
    private FrameLayout view_camera;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))) {
            this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture video_capture;

        Button button_symptoms = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_symptoms);
        Button button_upload_signs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_upload_signs);
        Button button_measure_heart_rate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_measure_heart_rate);
        Button button_measure_respiratory_rate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_measure_respiratory_rate);

        cv1 = new CameraView(getApplicationContext(), this);
        view_camera = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.view_camera);
        view_camera.addView(cv1);

        TextView finger_on_sensor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_finger_on_sensor);
        finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        finger_on_sensor.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg_view, MotionEvent arg_me) {
                finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                File file_video = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/video_finger.mp4");
                final int VIDEO_CAPTURE = 101;
                Intent intent_record_video = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT, 45);
                Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.cse535a1.provider", file_video);
                intent_record_video.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent_record_video, VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                return false;
            }

        });

        button_symptoms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Loggin_symptoms.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        button_upload_signs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {

            }
        });

        button_measure_heart_rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                finger_on_sensor.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        button_measure_respiratory_rate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg_view) {
                SensorManager manager_sensor = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
                Sensor sensor_accelerometer = manager_sensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
                manager_sensor.registerListener(MainActivity.this, sensor_accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setCam(Camera arg_camera) {
        c = arg_camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg_event) {
        float x = arg_event.values[0];
        float y = arg_event.values[1];
        float z = arg_event.values[2];
        Log.i("ACCELEROMETER", String.valueOf(x) + ' ' + String.valueOf(y) + ' ' + String.valueOf(z));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg_sensor, int arg_accuracy) {

    }

    public Camera getcam() {
        Camera c = null;
        try { c = Camera.open(0); }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        c.unlock();
//        if (c != null) {
//            c.stopPreview();
//            c.release();
//            c = null;
//        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
//        if (c != null) {
//            c.stopPreview();
//            c.release();
//            c = null;
//        }
//        cv1 = new CameraView(getApplicationContext(), this);
//        view_camera.addView(cv1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (c != null) {
            c.stopPreview();
            c.release();
            c = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**CameraView.java**

```
package com.example.cse535a1;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder holder_surface;
    private Camera camera_selected;
    MainActivity act1;

    public CameraView(Context arg_context, MainActivity arg_activity) {
        super(arg_context);
//        camera_selected = arg_camera;
        act1 = arg_activity;
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        holder_surface = getHolder();
        holder_surface.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        holder_surface.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg_holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
//            Log.i("CAMNULL", "CAM IS : " + String.valueOf(camera_selected == null));
            Camera c = null;
            try {
                c = Camera.open(0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("CAMERA", "Camera not opened");
            }
            act1.setCam(c);
            camera_selected = c;
            camera_selected.setPreviewDisplay(arg_holder);
//            camera_selected.startPreview();
//            Log.i("Cam", "surface creator");
        } catch (IOException e) {
//            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
//        if (camera_selected != null) {
//            camera_selected.stopPreview();
//            camera_selected.release();
//            camera_selected = null;
//        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg_holder, int arg_format, int arg_width, int arg_height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (holder_surface.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            camera_selected.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            camera_selected.setPreviewDisplay(holder_surface);
            camera_selected.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
//            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```